# control if email was already checked in gridview

Tags: c#, email, loops

I'll define the problem first. I have a gridview which has a column checkboxes and another column email adresses. If for example I select 3 rows out of 7 and these 3 rows have all the same email address, my code will send 3 emails to the address. Is it possible to get these 3 rows in 1 mail?

My current code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    CheckBox ck = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBoxATH");

    if (ck != null)
    {
   Label lblUsrE = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("LabelEmail");
       string emadr = lblUsrE.Text.ToString();

   if (ck.Checked == true)
       {
      MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
          mail.To.Add(emadr.ToString());
       }}}
```

I was thinking of another loop around lblUsrE, but I could use some help here.

Regards Mati

Comment: i think its simple to check bef you add and just send it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    CheckBox ck = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBoxATH");
    if (ck != null)
    {
      Label lblUsrE = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].FindControl("LabelEmail");
      string emadr = lblUsrE.Text.ToString();
      if (ck.Checked == true && !lst.Contains(emadr))
      {
        lst.Add(emadr);
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(emadr.ToString());
        ....
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hey jAX, I believe this works yes. I tested it and I receive only 1 email in my inbox. But the content of the email isn't correct. If I select 2 rows with same email address i get only the order row which the program met first in the db. So basicly my 2nd order isn't added to the email. Must be something else in my code. Ty for the help.